# Nominalisierung von "ausschlaggebend" möglich?

Tags: nominalization

Ich wollte in einem Text das Wort "Ausschlaggebung" verwenden, nur hat sich dann herausgestellt, dass das Wort nicht im Duden steht.

Auszug aus dem Satz:

> [...], wurde die Windlast aufgrund einer verhältnisweise geringen Ausschlaggebung vernachlässigt.

Wäre eine Nominalisierung falsch? Und welches Wort verwende ich am besten stattdessen, wenn ja.

---

Zur Verdeutlichung: es geht um die Erhaltung der physikalischen Facette in dem Wort "ausschlaggebend". Mir ist bewusst, dass es viele Umschreibungen gibt, aber die Frage ist in erster Linie: geht Ausschlaggebung?

"Auswirkung" wäre ein *near miss*, aber vernachlässigt eben die Idee des "nicht nur auswirken, sondern auch Ausschlag geben".

Comment: Can you add more context about how you tried to use  please? _Ausschlaggebend_ might be appropriate if used correctly.

Comment: I am asking about Ausschlaggeb**u**ng.

Comment: It's hard without context, but *gab den Ausschlag* may sound more natural and can be found in the [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Ausschlag). Can you add a sample sentence that is supposed to contain *Ausschlaggebung*?

Comment: @TheAwfulLanguage Im Text hab ich eh schon eine Umschreibung gewählt, ich wollte nur wissen, ob's eventuell doch ein passendes Nomen gibt, oder man dieses eben bilden darf.

Comment: @355durch113 _Signifikanz_, _Relevanz_ vielleicht,

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Das wäre näher an "Bedeutung", ich hab die Frage erneut ergänzt. Hoffe jetzt ist alles klar.

Comment: Wie wäre es mit *Erfolg*?

Comment: Natürlich *darf* man das Wort bilden. Ob es schön oder sinnvoll ist (oder gar nur "verständlich") ist ein anderes Ding. Nicht alles, was richtig ist, ist auch sinnvoll oder verständlich.

Comment: Welche "physikalische Facette" soll denn erhalten werden? Gibt's ne Anzeige, die ausschlägt und damit etwas signalisiert? Ich finde den Konstrukt verwirrend.

Comment: Mir ist bewusst, dass das Konstrukt kein gewöhnliches ist, aber ist es auch verboten? @harper Könnte man so sagen, ja (es gibt visuelle Ergebnisse, die sich halt kaum verändern).

Comment: @355durch113 verboten ist das nicht. Aber ich fürchte, es ist nur schwer verständlich. Das wird es dem Leser nicht leicht machen, den Inhalt zu erfassen. Eventuell solltest Du den Satz entsprechend umformulieren.

Answer (score 5):

Du hast ja selbst vorgeführt, dass diese Substantivierung möglich ist. Wenn ein Wort nicht im Duden steht, sagt etwas über den Duden aus, nicht aber über die deutsche Sprache. Die deutsche Sprache ist viel zu lebendig und flexibel um all ihre Facetten in einem Wörterbuch abbilden zu können.

Stilistisch ist das Wort vielleicht nicht die beste Wahl. Ich persönlich würde im vorliegenden Satz *»Auswirkung«* verwenden:

> (Diesmal) wurde die Windlast aufgrund einer verhältnisweise geringen Auswirkung vernachlässigt.

Auch *»Relevanz«* würde passen. Da muss man dann mit dem jeweiligen Kontext abstimmen.

---

Übrigens haben weder *»Ausschlaggebung«* noch *»Relevanz«* irgend eine physikalische Facette. Ein Wort, das hier passen würde und in der Physik definiert ist, ist die [Wirkung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirkung_(Physik)), das ist das Produkt aus Energie und Zeit (gemessen in Joulesekunden). Aber ich glaube nicht, dass das hier gemeint ist, daher würde ich sogar davon abraten, diesen Begriff hier zu verwenden.

---

Der Begriff *»Substantivierung«* ist in der deutschen Grammatik übrigens geläufiger als *»Nominalisierung«,* weil dieser Begriff auch eindeutiger ist. Es sind zwar alle Substantive Nomen, aber nicht alle Nomen sind Substantive. Insbesondere gehören z.B. die Adjektive zu den Nomen, daher kann man sie eigentlich gar nicht Nominalisieren, weil sie ja ohnehin schon Nomen sind. Siehe: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nomen

Trotzdem wird der Begriff *»Nominalisierung«* so verwendet, als würde er *»Substantivierung«* bedeuten. Daher ist seine Verwendung nicht falsch, aber eindeutiger und klarer ist der Begriff *»Substantivierung«*.

---

**Nachtrag**
(Antwort auf einen Kommentar)

Wenn mit der physikalischen Facette der Ausschlag der Nadel eines Seismographen gemeint ist, kann man ja genau das schreiben:

> (Diesmal) wurde die Windlast aufgrund eines verhältnisweise geringen Ausschlags der Nadel eines Seismographen vernachlässigt.

Comment: Zur physikalischen Facette: ich habe mir die Nadel eines Seismographen vorgestellt, die *ausschlägt*. // Interessant, das mit den Nomen, wusste gar nicht, dass zB auch Artikel Nomen sein können (zumindest laut Wikipedia ohne weiter nachzuforschen).

Comment: Bitte um Korrektur: Die Wirkung ist nicht das Produkt aus Energie und Zeit, sondern das Integral über die Lagerangefunktion, respektive der Zeit. Die Wirkung hat die Dimension von Energie mal Zeit. Bitte nicht beides durcheinander werfen :)

Comment: Das mit der Nadel im übertragenen Sinne.